# Sharepoint REST API is not returning any item for some users

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, task-list

When I try to fetch Sharepoint items from Task list using REST API, for some users, it is returning correct values. But, for some other users, it is not returning any values. This is the first time I am facing this kind of issue.

The URL for API call is,

`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Tasks')/Items?$select=Status,AssignedTo/Title&$expand=AssignedTo&$filter=(StartDate le '2018-11-12T10:09:17.660Z') and (Status ne 'Completed') and (AssignedTo/Title eq 'Olivia Mia')&$top=5000`

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution for this. The solution is,

1. Go to list settings
2. Click `Versioning settings`
3. Select option `Any user who can read items` under `Draft Item Security`